# Meteor.js: check field combination of Match.Optional and Match.OneOf

Tags: meteor

How can I do a combination of Match.Optional and Match.OneOf in checking data? I want the field to be optional but if assign by a data either String or Date type only? I've check the docs but didn't see a combination of it. Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
check(input, Match.Optional(Match.OneOf(String, Date)));
```

Comment: Haha my bad. I've already tried this before seeing your answer and was going to close my question but you answered right away. Haha This is the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: That's fine - I'm sure someone else will find it useful. :)